# Xcode4: empty environment variables in custom build pre-action / post-action

Tags: xcode, post, build, xcode4, action

I need to run a custom build script in xcode 4. The script is added as pre-action and executed properly. My problem is, that there are no [environment variables](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) available that could help me to access my project files.

I.e. I'm interested in `${PROJECT_DIR}`, `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}` and `${INFOPLIST_PATH}`. Unfortunately the variables are not set. The whole environment looks like that:

```
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-pc2V6P/Render 
BASH=/bin/sh
BASH_ARGC=() 
BASH_ARGV=() 
BASH_LINENO=([0]="0")
BASH_SOURCE=([0]="/Users/melle/Projects/rc-control/RC/Scripts/preBuild.sh")
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="3" [1]="2" [2]="48" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-apple-darwin10.0")
BASH_VERSION='3.2.48(1)-release' 
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003 
DIRSTACK=() 
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-VH6onm/org.x:0 
EUID=502
GROUPS=()
HOME=/Users/melle
HOSTNAME=zack.fritz.box
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
IFS=' '
LOGNAME=melle
MACHTYPE=x86_64-apple-darwin10.0
OPTERR=1
OPTIND=1
OSTYPE=darwin10.0
PATH=/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PIPESTATUS=([0]="0") 
POSIXLY_CORRECT=y 
PPID=43073 
PS4='+ ' 
PWD=/private/var/folders/h2/h2tdJ2dPF943jRjJXqjNX++++TM/-Tmp-
SCHEME_ACTION_NAME='Run Script' 
SHELL=/bin/bash 
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:posix 
SHLVL=3 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-LXX6Lp/Listeners 
TERM=dumb
TMPDIR=/var/folders/h2/h2tdJ2dPF943jRjJXqjNX++++TM/-Tmp-/ 
UID=502
USER=melle
_=PWD
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F6:0:0
```

Is this a bug in xcode4 or is it me, doing it totally wrong?

My current workaround is to abuse `${BASH_SOURCE}` to find the way back to my project directory...

**Update**: It looks like [this is a bug in xcode 4.0.1](https://devforums.apple.com/message/407615). If you enter the script directly into the Xcode window, at least the variable `${WORKSPACE_PATH}` is available.

Comment: I am now using 4.0.2 and getting the required environment variables. From "Schema" drop down select  "Edit Schema...", Select "Build" from left bar, and then "Pre-actions". In "Run Script" section, you will get a new option to select, "Provide build setting from" with a drop down with your targets. Please select your required one, except None:), you will get your required environment variables.

Comment: @Learner's answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding the script to the target's build phase rather than as a pre-action was a better solution in my case:

1. Select the Project in the project navigator.
2. Select your target.
3. Go to the Build Phases tab.
4. Add a new build phase (script).
5. Drag it above the compile sources phase.
6. Add whatever script you need there. You can access environment variables such as `${PROJECT_DIR}`.

You can even have it output all the environment variables in the Log Navigator for you.

Additionally, the working directory for any scripts you call will be set to the project's directory automatically.